# Rounded corner Textfiled without border color

Tags: android, text, flutter

I need a rounded corner `TextField`, I'm able to do this but it is showing the default border color. I tried changing `borderSide` but was unable to change the color (it was still black):

```
       TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                      Icons.person,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      // width: 0.0 produces a thin "hairline" border
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(90.0)),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white24)
                      //borderSide: const BorderSide(),
                    ),

                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontFamily: "WorkSansLight"),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white24,
                    hintText: 'Password'),
              ),
```

I need this and I don't want the focus line but the cursor should be white. I tried to change everything in `border` parameter but still no change.

I want:

[image]

I'm getting this:

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create a transparent border:

```
      final border = OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(90.0)),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.transparent,
            )
            );
```

Another option is using :

```dart
borderSide: BorderSide.none
```

And use it in `focusedBorder` and `border` properties, also add a Theme to set the cursor and hint Colors:

```
    Theme(
                  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                    cursorColor: Colors.red,
                    hintColor: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        focusedBorder: border,
                        border: border,
                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.person,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontFamily: "WorkSansLight"),
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white24,
                        hintText: 'Password'),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Still showing black color and `cursorColor` is not defined in  `TextFormField` but on focus, it is changing.

Comment: sorry, I was using an upper version of flutter, check my answer updated

Comment: should i change the `ThemeData` in `materialApp`?

Comment: depends of you, if you want the same theme property for all of your views then you should , otherwise only change the theme for your textfield.

Comment: yes :) ,if you are using that textfield more than one time I recommend you to create a statelesswidget with your textfield and theme inside.

Comment: Good it is working,  I'm changing label text color when I write something it is showing black color `labelText: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),` i do something like this but showing error.

Comment: it's labelStyle no labelText

Comment: you could use `borderSide: BorderSide.none` instead of transparent colored border.

Answer (score 28):

Set:

```
borderSide: BorderSide.none,
```

As in:

```
   TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  // width: 0.0 produces a thin "hairline" border
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(90.0)),
                  borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                ),

                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontFamily: "WorkSansLight"),
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.white24,
                hintText: 'Password'),
          ),
```